# Cluster member variables declaration by their type useful or not?

Tags: c++

Please have a look a the following code sample, executed on a Windows-32 system using Visual Studio 2010:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class LogicallyClustered
{
    bool _fA;
    int _nA;
    char _cA;

    bool _fB;
    int _nB;
    char _cB;
};

class TypeClustered
{
    bool _fA;
    bool _fB;

    char _cA;
    char _cB;

    int _nA;
    int _nB;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout << sizeof(LogicallyClustered) << endl; // 20
    cout << sizeof(TypeClustered) << endl; // 12

    return 0;
}
```

---

## Question 1

The `sizeof` the two classes varies because the compiler is inserting padding bytes to achieve an optimized memory allignment of the variables. Is this correct?

## Question 2

Why is the memory footprint smaller if I cluster the variables by type as in `class TypeClustered`?

## Question 3

Is it a good rule of thumb to always cluster member variables according to their type?
Should I also sort them according to their size ascending (bool, char, int, double...)?

**EDIT**

## Additional Question 4

A smaller memory footprint will improve data cache efficiency, since more objects can be cached and you avoid full memory accesses into "slow" RAM. So could the ordering and grouping of the member declaration can be considered as a (small) but easy to achieve performance optimization?

Comment: Unless you have specific memory requirements or have to share the structures (e.g. transporting them "as is" over the Internet), then I see no reason to format the structures the way you think looks best and fits best with your style of coding.

Comment: Smaller memory foot print equals better cache utilization equals better performance? So it could be a small but useful performance optimization, couldn't it?

Comment: Generally, one question per question is best.

Comment: @CodyGray: Yes, but they are all related and built on each other.

Comment: This smells a little bit like premature optimisation. Much about what you're asking is the compiler's job. Doing it yourself, by hand, leads to harder-to-read and less maintainable code for basically zero gain on any desktop or mobile platform. With respect to (2), have you tried turning on all compiler optimisations?

Comment: I would guess that if you have that many members that their order alone affects readability, the class isn't very readable either way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Absolutely correct.

2) It's not smaller because they are grouped, but because of the way they are **ordered and grouped**. For example, if you declare 4 `chars` one after the other, they can be packed into 4 byte. If you declare one `char` and immediately one `int`, 3 padding bytes will be inserted as the `int` will need to be aligned to 4 bytes.

3) No! You should group members in a class so that the class becomes more readable.

#### Important note: this is all platform/compiler specific. Don't take it ad-literam.

Another note - there also exist some small performance increase on some platforms for accessing members that reside in the first `n` (varies) bytes of a class instance. So declaring frequently accessed members at the beginning of a class can result in a small speed increase. However, this too shouldn't be a criteria. I'm just stating a fact, but in no way recommend you do this.

Answer (score 3):

You are right, the size differs because the compiler inserts padding bytes in class LogicallyClustered. The compiler should use a memory layout like this:

```
class LogicallyClustered 
{ 
    // class starts well aligned
    bool _fA;
    // 3 bytes padding (int needs to be aligned)
    int _nA; 
    char _cA; 

    bool _fB; 
    // 2 bytes padding (int needs to be aligned)
    int _nB; 
    char _cB; 
    // 3 bytes padding (so next class object in an array would be aligned)
};
```

Your `class TypeClustered` does not need any padding bytes because all elements are aligned. bool and char do not need alignment, int needs to be aligned on 4 byte boundary.

Regarding question 3 I would say (as often :-)) "It depends.". If you are in an environment where memory footprint does not matter very much I would rather sort logically to make the code more readable. If you are in an environment where every byte counts you might consider moving around the members for optimal usage of space.

Answer (score 2):

Unless there are no extreme memory footprint restrictions, cluster them **logically**, which improves code readability and ease of maintenance.

Comment: I see your point according the readability. But what do you think about the possible performance improvement (see added question 4)?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you actually have problems of space (i.e. very, very large
vectors with such structures), don't worry about it.  Otherwise: padding
is added for alignment: on most machines, for example, a `double` will
be aligned on an 8 byte boundary.  Regrouping all members according to
type, with the types requiring the most alignment at the start will
result in the smallest memory footprint.

Comment: What do you think about the argument: small memory footprint equals better cache performance (see question 4)?

Comment: If you're having performance issued due to cache misses when accessing instances of this struct, you might think about it.  Otherwise, why bother?

Answer (score 2):

Q1: Yes

Q2: Depends on the size of bool (which is AFAIK compiler-dependent). Assuming it is 1 byte (like char), the first 4 members together use 4 bytes, which is as much as is used by one integer. Therefore, the compiler does not need to insert alignment padding in front of the integers.

Q3: If you want to order by type, size-descending is a better idea. However, that kind of clustering impedes readability. If you want to avoid padding under all circumstances, just make sure that every variable which needs more memory than 1 byte starts at an alignment boundary.

The alignment boundary, however, differs from architecture to architecture. That is (besides the possibly different sizes of int) why the same struct may have different sizes on different architectures. It is generally safe to start every member x at an offset of a 
multiple of sizeof(x). I.e., in

```
struct {
   char a;
   char b;
   char c;
   int d;
}
```

The int d would start at an offset of 3, which is not a multiple of sizeof(int) (=4 on x86/64), so you should probably move it to the front. It is, however, not necessary to strictly cluster by type.

Some compilers also offer the possibility to completely omit padding, e.g. `__attribute((packed))__` in g++. This, however, may slow down your program, because an int then might actually need two memory accesses.

Comment: `__attribute((packed))__` may require far more than that: 2 reads, 2 bitshifts, and a combination.

Comment: @ovenror why would size-descending be a better idea?

Comment: @QuantumKarl: It is guaranteed to minimize the memory footprint of the compiled structure. Alignment requirements usually depend on the size of the type. Suppose you have a 4-byte integer, which has to be aligned at a 4-byte boundary, and a char, which does not have to be aligned. The structure with size-descending order would need 5 bytes of memory, while it would be 8 bytes with reversed order, because the compiled would have to introduce 3 padding bytes after the char.